# Can't get rid of wdm

Tags: ubuntu-minimal, xinit

I have a minimal installation of Ubuntu 14.04 with `dwm` as window manager.

The display manager `wdm` was installed as a dependency and is launched at every boot.
But all I want is a manual login to X with `startx` (`.xinitrc` is configured with `exec dwm`).

- I disabled the service `wdm` using `bum`, but when I launch `startx` I got the error message

  ```
  Only root wants to run wdm
  ```
- The same error message appears after removing wdm completely with its dependencies.
- I also modified in vain the parameter `splash quiet` of `/etc/default/grub` to `text`.

I used to setup Debian and ArchLinux systems without having this problem. Is it specific to Ubuntu? What is the proper way to resolve my issue? I hope there won't be a confusion concerning the couple `wdm`/`dwm` ...